# Create Entity database

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem creating a Database with Entity Code First. I have a console application, and in `App.config` my connection string is:

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="PointOfSaleContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial 
      Catalog=PointOfSale; Integrated Security=SSPI;  
     Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I've made a public model class with public fields, and class with Context:

```
public class PointOfSaleContext : DbContext
{
    public PointOfSaleContext() : base("PointOfSaleContext")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Problem is that database doesn't get created. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it's not being created? What's the error you see?

Comment: Sure it's not created as that looks fine

Comment: Yes, I checked in Sql server object explorer and in computer folder.

Comment: I don't see any errors...

Comment: you try connecting to (localDB)\v11.0  or (localdb)\ProjectsV12 ?

Comment: Problem Is done, thank's for help!

Comment: @Lukas25 - What was the answer?  If you found the answer on your own, please post it as an answer.

Comment: @PhilipPittle I'd say it was obviously being created, but let's wait for an answer! :-)

Comment: Why do you use `Integrated Security` twice in your connection string?

Comment: Because database was displayed in sql server(VS 2013) after I inserted some data in base.